# Release a queue in ARC

Tags: xcode, queue, automatic-ref-counting, release

I create a queue in which I do a printing background task:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _queue = dispatch_queue_create("q.myqueue.com", nil);
    dispatch_set_finalizer_f(self.queue, &myFinalizerFunction);
    background = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    t = nil;

    [self beginBackgroundTask];
}

- (void)beginBackgroundTask {
    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        background = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [self endBackgroundTask];
        }];

        NSLog(@"background created: %d", background);

        t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(printIt)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t
                                     forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; // NSDefaultRunLoopMode
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    });
}

- (void)endBackgroundTask {
    NSLog(@"Ending background");

    if (t!=nil) {
        [t invalidate];
        t = nil;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:background];
    background = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    NSLog(@"Ended!");
}
```

After the background expires, `[self endBackgroundTask]` is called; but when I monitor on Xcode debug by "Pause Program Execution", I still see the queue "q.myqueue.com" there!

```
Thread 2
Queue: q.myqueue.com
0 mach_msg_trap
7 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]
8 __37-[ViewController beginBackgroundTask]_block_invoke
9 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
14 _pthread_wqthread
```

Can anybody explain why the queue "q.myqueue.com" is still there in Xcode debug after the background task is expired? I want to use `dispatch_release(self.queue)` but ARC refuses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've got a strong reference to the queue. The queue will stay there as long as _queue isn't set to nil. And setting _queue = nil is all you need to do. Remember that the queue will stay alive as long as any tasks are running on it.

By the way, the only developers playing around with run loops are those who are either really clever or really stupid. I stay away from them as much as I can.

Comment: Thanks, gnasher729. Agree, I do not want to play with run loops either! But I need a timer working in background, so I am afraid that I have no other choices. If I comment `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];` or `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];` or both, the timer does not work! Have you got a better way? I would love to know.